# "Crystal radius" vs "Ionic radius"

Tags: ions, atomic-radius

What is the difference between *crystal radius* and *ionic radius*? For $\ce{NaCl}$ for example the ions combine to a crystal, and I would have guessed they are equal. But I then found an example of data, where they are not.

I am aware that [ionic radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_radius) is the radius of an atom's ion. Quite simple. So what is *crystal radius*?

Comment: I have found two different uses of the term "Crystal Radius." First is [Linus Pauling's use of Crystal Radaii](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022190265800379), which refers to ions that are free and not part of a crystal. The second is used to describe some parameters of the flame fusion crystal growth [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=6580068), which would seem to be very much incorporated into the crystalling structure. This seems to be a rarely encountered term. Where did you encounter it?

Comment: Similar question: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Difference_between_Crystal_Ionic_Radius_and_Effective_Ionic_Radius

Comment: There is a table of "[Pauling Empirical Crystal Radiuses](http://www.knowledgedoor.com/2/elements_handbook/pauling_empirical_crystal_radius.html#sthash.tCVsV13k.dpuf)", which cites the following sources: Galasso, Francis S. Structure and Properties of Inorganic Solids. Oxford: Pergamon Press, 1970.
Pauling, Linus. The Nature of the Chemical Bond, 3rd edition. Ithaca, NY: Cornell University Press, 1960.
Rohrer, Gregory S. Structure and Bonding in Crystalline Materials. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2001.

Answer (score -3):

To quote Erik Rakovský · 30.73  · 54.96 · Comenius University in Bratislava (from [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Difference_between_Crystal_Ionic_Radius_and_Effective_Ionic_Radius#view=56b050e07dfbf9d1cf8b4583) discussion on researchgate)

Shannon published simultaneously two sets of ionic radii. So called "effective ionic radii" were made consistent with Pauling's r($\mathrm{O_2^-}$)=140 pm. "Crystal radii" are using Shannon's value r($\mathrm{O_2^-}$)=126 pm.

https://dx.doi.org/10.1107%2FS0567739476001551

Comment: Could you please summarise the content of these links?

Comment: @Gerhard The description is already above each link respectively.

Comment: This answer would have been more helpful if you would have explained what all there is in those links and then provided them as source. Just saying.

Comment: @Quark If you edit it, I will approve it.

Comment: @Dale  Only If I understood what the correct answer is. Haha.

Comment: People come to SE for answers, not for links.